# pass four latitude and longitude in google api one by one and find distance one to another in one array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach, google-api

i have four diff. location and there lat long.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [P_lat] => 23.033179200000000000
            [P_long] => 72.516751900000030000
            [N_lat] => 23.0061
            [N_long] => 72.5647
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [P_lat] => 23.2200
            [P_long] => 72.6800
            [N_lat] => 23.027126200000000000
            [N_long] => 72.507963199999950000
        )

)
```

and i have one function to call google api and find distance between two location.

```
function getTime($org_lat,$org_long,$des_lat,$des_long)
{

    $url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$org_lat,$org_long&destinations=$des_lat,$des_long&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false";

 $data = @file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($data, true);
 $r=explode(' ', $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text']);
 return $r[0];
}
```

this function return time.
i want to pass one by one all my four lat long like

```
1). first object p_lat p_long , first object n_lat n_long
2). first object p_lat p_long , second object p_lat p_long
3). first object p_lat p_long, second object n_lat n_long
4). first object n_lat n_long, first object p_lat p_long
5). first object n_lat n_long, second object p_lat p_long
6). first object n_lat n_long, second object n_lat n_long
7). second object p_lat p_long, second object n_lat n_long
8). second object p_lat p_long, first object p_lat p_long
9). second object p_lat p_long, first object n_lat n_long
10). second object n_lat n_long, first object p_lat p_long
11). second object n_lat n_long, first object n_lat n_long
12). second object n_lat n_long, second object p_lat p_long
```

here i am done this but i am calling 12 time individual getTime() function.
i want to do something like logical with loop or foreach.
thanks.